# How can I get the data transfered data from jQuery.getJSON within the PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I have a Javascript variable whatToRefresh which is defined in this way:

```
var whatToRefresh = 
{
    "online" : true,
    "running" : false,
    "detail" : 0
};
```

This variable is used within a getJSON to tell the php file what data are requested:

```
$.getJSON("scripts/php/RequestData.php", whatToRefresh, function(data) { PopulateData(data); });
```

Now I need the data within the PHP file but this returns all the time null:

```
$requestData = json_decode(($_GET['data']), true);
```

How can I access this data within php?

Comment: I don't see a get variable called data. Your get variables are going to be online, running and detail.

Comment: Thank you too! $_GET['online'] and so on works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just access $_GET['online'],  $_GET['running'],  $_GET['detail']. try to see that - var_dump($_GET);

Answer (score 3):

Where you're getting confused is, the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

JSON is **not** being sent to the server, so you do not need to decode it with `json_decode`.

This jQuery method is just sending an HTTP `get` request, with a query string that has your variables in it.  The `$.getJSON` method *expects* to see a JSON *response* from the server, hence the `json` in the name.